# How do I use DISTINCT ON in queryDSL with booleanBuilder parameter?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

In Spring Data JPA I have created a filtered search with `BooleanBuilder`. The queries in my project are either with `@Query` or `QueryDSL`. But I'm having a hard time formulating a query when I'm faced with the `DISTINCT ON` and dynamic filters. I'm having a hard time constructing the equivalent of this in QueryDSL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) *
 FROM foo_table
 WHERE <my filtered booleanBuilder>
 ORDER  BY name, version_number DESC;
```

Is this possible? Any alternative or help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT ON` is a PostgreSQL vendor-specific SQL clause. You cannot use it with JPA (except with native queries). Use it with SQL directly.

Comment: I can't use native queries because the _WHERE_ clause is not fixed. Do you have any suggestions for a workaround? In the database I have duplicate names but I only want to fetch the highest version of that name together with the `WHERE` clause taken into account.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Why can't you use native queries? You can write dynamic SQL also with native queries...

Comment: I thought there's a way to filter by a `BooleanBuilder` since it's easier to implement. But I guess it is not possible for complex queries so, yes, I'm using native queries now in my code. It's a pain to look at but it'll do for now. Thanks for the help.